# Full review or excerpt for Schema.org's "reviewBody"

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

I'm using rich snippets to my blog, my blog is about movies, there is a section call "reviewBody":
There you can write (or copy paste) your review.

Should I paste all my review or just an excerpt from my review?

Because I think that Google just take a summary, but I don't know if I have to paste everything or just a summary.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google’s [Review snippet](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet?hl=en) documentation, Google doesn’t make use of the `reviewBody` property, as it’s not listed under "Required properties" nor "Recommended properties".

If you provide this property, it has to contain the full review, per [its definition](https://schema.org/reviewBody):

> The actual body of the review.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this resource from Google specifically tailored for your question: 
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet

Google broke done each JSON-LD property tag with a full description; you can also test your code before publishing using the structured data markup test tool (also by Google): https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/